# C++ declaring multiple integers prints different values

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, variable-declaration

I am trying to learn c++ and I came across a very annoying inconsistency:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    int var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7;

    cout << var1 << endl;
    cout << var2 << endl;
    cout << var3 << endl;
    cout << var4 << endl;
    cout << var5 << endl;
    cout << var6 << endl;
    cout << var7 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It returns the following:

```
0
4196128
0
570985680
32767
0
0
```

Why am I getting different values for these unset values? Shouldn't I get either 0 for each variable? What does the output that I am getting represent?

Comment: you didn't initialized them, so they have random value.

Comment: "What does the output that I am getting represent?", undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninitialized local variables will have *indeterminate* values, which will seem random. Reading their indeterminate value leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 1):

Reading from an uninitialised `int` is undefined behaviour. The output you see may be the data currently stored in the memory locations reserved for your variables.

But that's not important, because anything could happen; the important thing is to prevent undefined behaviour, and this is best done here by initialising your variables:

```
int var1 = 0;
int var2 = 0;
// and so on
```

Also note that your compiler can surely can warn you about this if you use an appropriate **warning level**. Look it up in your compiler's documentation and get into the habit of not ignoring any warnings.